# MongoDB aggregate accounting info

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am completely new to MongoDB aggregation. I currently, have a collection in which I save a few account names:

**accounts**: _id: ObjectId; name: String

Example: Items: ObjectId(...) "Bank account" etc

On top of that, I have a journal collection, in which I store accounting journal entries. They look the following:

**journals**: _id: ObjectId, debit: (Ref to accounts id), credit: (Ref to accounts id); amount

The idea is, that I save accounting entries like the following: 
Debit: (Id of "Bank Account"), Credit: (Id of "Share Capital")

Now, I am trying to use the aggregate get the total debit, total credit, and total sum (debit-credit) for all account types.

Now, I **kind of** this to work for only one specific account type:

```
db.journals.aggregate(
{ $project: {
    _id: 0,
    PosSentiment: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$debit',  ObjectId("5a809cf86ce518470ec92502")]}, '$amount', 0]},
    NegSentiment: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$credit',  ObjectId("5a809cf86ce518470ec92502")]}, '$amount', 0]}
}},
{ $group: {
    _id: 0,
    debit: {$sum: '$PosSentiment'},
    credit: {$sum: '$NegSentiment'}
}});
```

Unfortunately, this only gives me credit and debit for **one** type of account that I specific in the ObjectId, I don't have the total and I have to run this for every account.

Is there a possibility to use aggregates to end up with a result like this
[{_id: ..., name (from account collection), totaldebit, totalcredit, total}]?

Thank you very much!

Comment: could you provide your document examples as JSON, it’s quite hard to follow your code at present. If you can provide complete documents then it makes it easier for everyone to create a test collection. It sound like a use case for `$lookup`, please also state your mongo version :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.journals.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"accounts",
    "localField":"debit",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"debit"
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"accounts",
    "localField":"credit",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"credit"
  }},
  {"$project":{
     "data":[
       {name:"$debit","type":"debit"},
       {name:"$credit","type":"credit"}
    ],
    "amount":1
   }},
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"account":{"$arrayElemAt":["$data.name",0]},"type":"$data.type"},
    "total":{"$sum":"$amount"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.account._id",
    "name":{"$first":"$_id.account.name"},
    "balances":{$push:{"type":"$_id.type","total":"$total"}},
    "alltotal":{"$sum":"$total"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify answer ?